# z3 Python API: Optimize() + timeout = segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, timeout, z3py

I'm using the z3 Python API (version 4.4.2) for an optimization problem using `z3.Optimize()`.

I get a segmentation fault problem when setting a `timeout`. The problem disappears once I remove the timeout of set a `soft-timeout`; however, in both cases, the solver does not finish.

I tried to get more insight by setting the verbose option

```
z3.set_option("verbose", 10)
```

but I don't get any information at all. Is this normal?

Is there any known issue with `z3.Optimize()` and `timeout`? If not, can anybody give me some pointer in order to obtain further information about where the problem is coming from.